# Implement an Expandable Android Recycler View with Sticky Headers, Search Function, Alphabetical Side Selector and Swipable Items/cards?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

This seems a very specific question but it is actually relevant to real world apps.

Often the requirements for the application entails that a `ListView` or for future proof sake a `RecyclerView` that has the following:

- `StickyHeaders`
- `Search` Functionality
- An `Alphabetical SectionIndexer` Fast Scroll
- `Swipable` items for extra functions
- Expandable

So there are a few libraries that can do single tasks on the list:

- [StickyHeadersRecyclerView](https://github.com/timehop/sticky-headers-recyclerview)
- [StickHeadersListView](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders)
- [SwipeableListView](https://github.com/hudomju/android-swipe-to-dismiss-undo)
- [SectionIndexerFastScroll](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/12/android-listview-sectionindexer-fastscroll.html)

However these libraries don't work well together and often can't extend each other. Are there any ideas how to have the functionality of all these classes together?

Comment: You probably have to roll your own library. You may want to look to see if anyone has already implemented a similar library in [android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com) though.

Comment: hey bro now i'm facing same issue i want to combine sticky header recycler view with expandable recycler view.but i'm out of luck have you found a solution ?

Comment: I Had same issue with expandable sticky header (with grid layout), I achieved this by combining these libraries: [SuperSLiM](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM) and [Advanced RecyclerView](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-advancedrecyclerview), But have a little problem , I get a blink when I try to change `LayoutParams` (on expanding and collapsing), Still working on it...